# Undergraduate questions

Tags: discussion, undergraduate

I think we have discussed undergraduate questions a couple of times on meta, but I cannot find anything that looks relevant. I think we are closing questions by undergraduate too quickly.

**The following seem on topic to me:**

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15713/struggling-as-an-undergraduate-international-student is a question by an undergraduate about improving a CV for getting into grad school.

[Will going to an university in UK be profitable for me in the future?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15941/will-going-to-an-university-in-uk-be-profitable-for-me-in-the-future) is a question by a US high school student about whether doing an international undergraduate degree would prepare someone for US graduate school.

[Preparing a curriculum vitae for an undergraduate internship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/preparing-a-curriculum-vitae-for-an-undergraduate-internship) about an undergraduate writing a CV for a research internship

**As a contrast, these closed question seem off topic to me:**

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15576/is-a-second-undergraduate-degree-worthwhile about getting a second undergraduate degree to prepare for a job industry

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15430/standardized-tests-for-international-students-for-entry-in-top-us-uk-colleges which is about undergraduate admissions without any concern for graduate admissions

Comment: I agree with your and aeismail's classification. Unfortunately, it seems that some users simply vote to close whenever they see the word undergraduate, without looking further.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for posting this.

The general rule is that questions should be generalizable to non-undergraduates, or at the very least be related to the conduct of research. I agree that the first two questions you posted as "on topic" should be open—and I reopened the first one. (The second one remains open.)

I agree that the third question is on-topic, but I disagree about opening it, because it should have been closed under the "too specific" rubric, rather than the "undergraduate" option.

The last two are definitely off-topic.

If you think that a question should be reopened, the best way to go about this is to put a reopen vote; then it will begin to show up under the "review" tag, so that people with appropriate levels of reputation can vote accordingly.

Comment: I agree that my 3rd example question probably should be left closed as too localized. I just want to make sure that we don't use "undergrad" as a reason to close too liberally.