# Should a undergrad-level question be down-voted?

Tags: discussion, undergraduate

e.g.

[Harvard Multiple authors- Alphabetical or not?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18723/harvard-multiple-authors-alphabetical-or-not)

I was surprised to see it down-voted. The question may appear stupid to the majority of users here, but I can understand it being a legitimate question from an undergrad.

So, should a question related to academia, but not relevant to postgrad students be down-voted?

(different to [Undergraduate questions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/754/undergraduate-questions) because these are not specific to an undergraduate situation, but are of the level of understanding that an undergrad would have about academic writing)

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it was badly asked, not because it seemed to be a "stupid question." (Although probably some people downvoted it for the latter reason, too, and I disagree that they should have.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the downvote is probably a little harsh, but the question in question is just not very good or interesting. It also is not particularly clear in that the OP refers to a set of Harvard guidelines, but doesn't tell us which ones. This might be worthy of an downvote accompanied by a comment.