# Where can I ask undergraduate questions?

Tags: discussion, undergraduate

I recently posted a question about undergraduate acceptance of older students.

[Is it much more difficult to enter an Ivy League much later in life?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/50141/is-it-much-more-difficult-to-enter-an-ivy-league-much-later-in-life)

It is currently on hold because it seems like undergraduate questions are off topic. While I believe that such a question is clearly 'academia', my main concern is where exactly would it be acceptable to post a question like this? Shouldn't 'Academia' be a default forum for undergraduates until a more appropriate forum opens up?

Comment: Also see ["I couldn't find a better SE site for this question" is not necessarily a reason to ask it here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1273/11365) in the [Welcome to Academia.SE](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se) post.

Comment: @ff524 Thanks; I thought I remembered seeing a definitive statement like this, but couldn't find it.  Is there any way that we can get the "Welcome to Academia" post into the site help center?

Answer (score 4):

It is a general principle on StackExchange that a question isn't on topic just because it would be more off-topic elsewhere.  Thus, there is no such thing as a "default site" in the StackExchange model.

Some undergraduate-related questions *are* on topic here, if they also strongly relate to non-undergraduate aspects of academic life (see, e.g., [this meta question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/754/22733)).  Unfortunately, at present there is no StackExchange site that is aimed at primarily undergraduate issue---I believe it's been proposed once or twice on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), but been unable to gain sufficient momentum to launch.

For the present then, I'm afraid that you would be best advised to ask this question in a different forum system.

Comment: I understand, but it is still strange because it's weird to have questions closed as "off-topic" on the site that fits them best. Especially since it's probably not obvious to many people that "academia" does not include undergraduates (or what counts as undergraduates, for that matter... middle school probably does, and post-doctorals probably don't, but I'm less sure about the intermediate stages). <continued in the next comment...>

Comment: <continued from previous comment, too long> Are there other big examples of question topics that are off-topic (no pun intended) on their best-fitting StackExchange site? (For that matter, is there anything that's off-topic on its best-fitting SE site but technically on-topic on another SE site that otherwise doesn't fit it as well?) And incidentally, is the "general principle" referred to officially listed anywhere?

Comment: Business aspects of music are off-topic on music, and business aspects of video game development are off-topic on gamedev.